# vsocde-remote SSH ,How to use user snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

My local system is a Windows 10 system

The remote system is Linux Ubuntu

After using remote for a while, I noticed that it did not enable the code snippet I had previously written

So I tried to make the code snippet available to the remote system, but I failed in the following two attempts:

1. Look for relevant options in the vscode settings, but the settings there can only write fragments for my local vscode, not for remote vscode
2. Attempted to manually create the '$HOME/. config/Code/User/snippets' folder under Linux and copy the content of the previously written fragment file (recreated the file, kept the file name consistent, and then pasted the content), but this still did not take effect

---

Can vscode remote still not use user code snippets?

If possible, what should be done?